# Use a table called "external"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database called `MOSAIQ` with a table called `external`.  When I try even a simple query in SQL Server management studio I get a response

> Incorrect Syntax near 'External'. Expecting '.', ID, or QUOTED_ID

e.g.

```
SELECT E.PNP_ID
FROM Mosaiq.dbo.External E
```

I have tried using Alias/not alias with no luck. Could someone much smarter than me please assist

Answer (score 2):

EXTERNAL is a reserved word.
[Reserved Keywords (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

You should quote the table name.

```
[External]
```

or

```
"External"
```

Comment: Thanks soooo much Dudu. Worked a treat and so simple.  I cannot thank you enough